# alignment issue with the down-arrow for select tag

Tags: css, select, alignment, dropdown

I have one `form` in which I have one field for `City Name` 
I am facing one issue with the `down-arrow` alignment, currenlty I have `aligned` that to the `right` with `background` property

**something like this**

```
background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right white;
```

[image]

but you can see its touching the `border` of an div, I want to add some `spacing` from the `right` 
so that I have an `equal spacing`

I have tried adding `padding`, `margin`, `left` and `right` properties but the whole div get move of `city code`

can someone tell me what's the exact issue with this?

**EDIT:**
added code snippet

```css
.cityName {
    display: flex;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-inputs{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #445566;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cityName select {
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.cityName select.city-short{
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right white;
    background-size: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="lastName" class="cityName">
   <input type="text" id="cityName" placeholder="Enter City Name" class="city validated form-inputs">
   <select class="city-short form-inputs">
      <option selected="" value="" >NA
      </option>
      <option selected="" value="" >US
      </option>
   </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add background position size for background property like:

```
background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right 10px center white
```